# Alt + Space to open menu in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint

On my MacBook, I can press the Spacebar and the key next to it, which will open a prompt allowing me to search all applications.  The same thing is available on Linux Mint, but I have to click the 'Menu' icon on the bottom left (the equivalent of the Windows start button.)

Is there a way to assign a key combination which will open the main system Menu?  I am unable to find it in the Keyboard configuration, although other key combinations are available.  If there is a command to launch the menu bar from a terminal instance, I could add that as a hotkey combination.

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a Windows-style keyboard, you can just hit the Super (Windows) key. I'm not sure about Mac keyboards, but you can try hitting each key on the bottom row individually to see if any one of them opens the menu.

Additionally, you can specify a new keyboard shortcut by right-clicking the menu icon, clicking Configure, and setting one of two keyboard shortcut options at the top of the applet settings window.

Comment: That works - I didn't even try it before!  If I can't get Alt+Space to do the same thing, this will work.  However, I would like to have it the same as my Mac so I can keep movements the same between computers.  Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: Actually, yes. I don't know why I didn't think of it before, but right click on the menu launcher icon and choose Configure. Then at the top you can choose two keyboard shortcuts to launch the menu.

Comment: That is perfect!!  Exactly what I needed!  Thank you so much for the help, this will make my transition to Mint much easier as I use this very frequently!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. :-)